# Subgroup Decision Problem

Tags: group-theory

Let $x \in G$ be an element of a group $G$ of order $n = pq$. $G_p$ and $G_q$ are prime order sub-groups of order $p$ and $q$ respectively. How can we prove that $x^q \in G_p$?

I want to understand the given definition of Subgroup Decision problem as defined by Boneh. Doesn't it essentially translate to what I stated earlier?

---

[image: subgroup-decision]

Comment: Are $p$ and $q$ different? Dos $G_p$ have order $p$ and $G_q$ has order $q$?

Comment: Adam Hughes's answer shows that this claim is false without further assumptions.  Take $x$ to be a transposition in $S_3$ with $p=2$, $q=3$.  Then $x^q$ has order $2$ but only lies in one of the three possible choices for $G_2$.

Comment: I have added further detail to the original question to clarify certain points. Please have a look at it.

Comment: Let's say, elements of $S_3$ are $e_1=(1,2,3)$, $e_2=(1,3,2)$, $e_3=(2,1,3)$, $e_4=(2,3,1)$,$e_5=(3,1,2)$ and $e_6=(3,2,1)$. Then what all are those transpositions you are referring to?

Answer (score 6):

Lagrange's theorem says the order of an element divides the order of the group, so

$$\text{ord}(x)|pq\implies \text{ord}(x^q)|pq/q=p$$

so $x^q$ is in *some* group of order $p$. However, there is not necessarily only $1$. Take, for example, $S_3$, the symmetric group on three symbols, which has three conjugate groups of order $2$, which one would you pick there?

Comment: $ord(S_3) = 6$, but the statement requires $p * q = 6$ while it is $2 * 2 = 4$ in this case.

Comment: No, p=2, q=3, how are you getting 2 x 2?

Comment: Let's say, elements of $S_3$ are $e_1=(1,2,3)$, $e_2=(1,3,2)$, $e_3=(2,1,3)$, $e_4=(2,3,1)$,$e_5=(3,1,2)$ and $e_6=(3,2,1)$. Then what all are those three conjugate groups you are referring to?

Comment: The elements of $S_3$ are $e, (1 2), (23), (13), (123), (321)$. The three conjugate groups are $\{e, (12)\}, \{e,(23)\}, \{e, (13)\}$.

Comment: @Holmes.Sherlock If you are wondering why our lists differ, note that many of yours are repeats: $(123)=(231)$, for example.

Comment: Many thanks Adam Hughes, I got it now.

Comment: @Holmes.Sherlock Glad to hear it! Since you're new I'll add a general piece of advice:  when you consider your questions settled on this site, it's considered proper to accept the answer you found most helpful (you can only accept one) to show the community you consider the matter closed. Best of luck and welcome to MSE.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if $x^q$=e then $x^q\in G_p$
If $x^q\neq e$, then the order of $x$ is $p$....